# Return string array from asp.net web service to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web service which returns a string currently and I want it to return a string array.
My js code looks like this:

```
function getMenu(menuID) {
    $("#open").css('display', 'block');
    $("#close").css('display', 'none');
    $('#flash_container').flash({
        swf: 'mainGallery.swf',
        width: "100%",
        height: 330,
        wmode: "transparent",
        quality: "high",
        flashvars: { XMLFile: 'xml/' + menuID + '.xml' }
    });

    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow", function() {
        var language;
        if (getParameterByName('language') == 'en')
            language = 1;
        else
            language = 0;

        GetMenu.CreateMenu(menuID, language, OnGotMenu, OnFail, "XmlDocument");

    });

}

function OnGotMenu(result) {
    var lblOutput = document.getElementById("lblOutput");
    lblOutput.innerHTML = result;

    $(".MenuList a:last").removeAttr('border-left');

    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $("#open").css('display', 'none');
    $("#close").css('display', 'block');
    fleXenv.fleXcrollMain("panel_content");
}
```

Now I return a string. I want to return string[].

How do I need to modify my js code to use this array?

**Edit:** Here is the c# code after the change proposed by @pukipuki (only the relevant part)

```
table.RenderControl(tw);
        string retVal = "[\"" + menuDIV + sb.ToString() + "\", \"" + currTitle + "\"]";
        return retVal.ToString();
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

**Edit 2:** Better version of the c# code:

```
table.RenderControl(tw);
    retArray[0] = menuDIV + sb.ToString();
    retArray[1] = currTitle;
    string retVal = jsSer.Serialize(retArray);
    return retVal;
```

But I still don't get an array I can access like:

```
var that = result[0];
var oranother = result[1];
```

etc.

Comment: where is the part when you call the web service in your code?

Comment: I call it via asp.net ajax. GetMenu.CreateMenu()

Comment: find a proper .ToJson() library for your ASP.NET code because what you're currently doing is very prone to errors

Comment: @keymone - Already considered this. Posting another version of the code.

Comment: what *do* you get? can you post responseText from javascript onSuccess callback?

Comment: try "eval(result)" first. Coz, the "result" is still a string.

Answer (score 1):

You should return data in format like:

```
[ "array", "elements", "here" ]
```

and then you will be able to index through result.

Comment: Tried it. It does not work. I add the c# code to my post. Maybe the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, you pushed me in the right direction.
The solution was to add `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Then I just return the string array as-is and the framework converts it to JSON.
Back in the js code I can now just access the fields using result[0], result[1], etc.